# An object reference is required to access non-static member

Tags: c#, mono

I have a timer and I want to put timer callbacks
into separate functions, however, I get this error.

> An object reference is required to access non-static field, method, or property ''...

If I declare these callbacks as delegate events and 
member variables as static, it works fine. Should I leave it that way?

```
class MainClass
{
    private Timer _timer = null;
    private TimeSpan _millisecs;

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Application.Init();
        MainWindow win = new MainWindow();

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "00:00";

        Table tbl = new Table(2, 2, true);
        tbl.Name = "tbl";

        Button btn = new Button("Start");
        tbl.Attach(lbl, 0, 2, 0, 1);
        tbl.Attach(btn, 0, 1, 1, 2);
        Button btn_stop = new Button("Stop");
        tbl.Attach(btn_stop, 1, 2, 1, 2);

        btn.Clicked += StartClick;
        btn_stop.Clicked += StopClick;

        win.Add(tbl);
        win.ShowAll();

        Application.Run ();
    }

    private void StartClick(object obj, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (_timer == null) {
            _timer = new Timer();
            _timer.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
                _millisecs = _millisecs.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50));
                lbl.Text = new DateTime(_millisecs.Ticks).ToString("ss:ff");
            };
            _timer.Interval = 50;
            _timer.Enabled = true;                  
        }

        _timer.Start();             
    }

    private void StopClick(object obj, EventArgs args)
    {
        _timer.Stop();          
    }

}
```

Comment: why not use Application.Run(new MainWindow()); then subscribe the events inside the class?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends what you're trying to do. You can *either* make things static, *or* you can create an instance:

```
MainClass instance = new MainClass();
btn.Clicked += instance.StartClick;
btn_stop.Clicked += instance.StopClick;
```

I assume this isn't your *real* application, so it's hard to say what you should do in your real code. Personally I'd lean towards creating an instance - static variables represent global state which is *usually* a bad idea (in terms of testability etc). We can't tell whether that affects your situation or not though.

What's important is that you understand *why* you're getting the error message and why the above change fixes it. Once you understand that, you'll be in a better situation to make the best decisions.

Comment: Yes, it's clear now. And I should probably put my timer class in a separate file. Thanks!

Comment: Odd that this worked in my case, but it was basically just what I needed.  Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are accessing non-static methods from the static in this case.

Either create object of the class and than call the method

```
ObjectOfClass obj = new ObjectOfClass();
obj.MethodName();
```

so in your case

```
MainClass obj = new MainClass();
btn.Clicked += obj.StartClick;
btn_stop.Clicked += obj.StopClick;
```

Or create the called methods as static (which you already tried as you said).