# An Object reference is required to access non-static member C# Unity - How do I fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting the following error

> Assets/Zoning.cs(12,30):  error CS0120: An object reference is
>   required  to access non-static member
>   `PlayerController.AddFuel(float)'

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("Player is Re-Fueling");
        PlayerController.AddFuel(1);
    }
```

Comment: You need to create a new playercontroller (or use one you already created) `var pc = new PlayerController(); pc.AddFuel(1);`

Comment: If PlayerController is a script you have on this same gameObject, then you will probably need to call GetComponent<PlayerController>() instead, to get the actual instance.

Comment: Linked [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992681/an-object-reference-is-required-to-access-non-static-member) contains good explanation of the error (also I assume you've already found some while researching your question). I'd recommend updating your question with set of issues that are still unclear after reading linked question so the post can be re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must create an instance of the class in order to access the functions inside it.

```
 PlayerController obj = new PlayerController();
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {
     if (collider.tag == "Player")
     {
         Debug.Log("Player is Re-Fueling"); 
         obj.AddFuel(1);
     }
```

Comment: I have fuel for this player on another script, this method causes me to creates an entire new fuel var. Is there a way to access to fuel from the original PlayerController?

Comment: in which case you can move PlayerController obj = new PlayerController();    on top of the method void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider). I have edited my answer.

Comment: @DanielBell pass that object as a parameter to this function