# An object reference is required to access non-static member `GroupMovement.rnd'

Tags: c#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GroupMovement : MonoBehaviour {

Random rnd = new Random();
public static short Round = 0;
public static int rGroup;
public static void SendGroup()
{
     rGroup = rnd.Next(2);

    switch (Round) {
    case 0:
        switch(rGroup)
        {
        case 0:
            Group_1.Group1_Active = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            break;
        }
        break;

    }
    Round ++;
}
```

}

Comment: Please, see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992681/an-object-reference-is-required-to-access-non-static-member?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the rnd variable is not static and you want to use it in static property, so make other fields and property not static or make the rnd static. Here how you can make rnd static.

```
public static Random rnd = new Random();
```