# How to call a non static method in the main?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //I want to call the bird method here
        }

        public void bird(Program program)
        {
            birdSpeech();
        }

        public void birdSpeech()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Chirp Chirp");
        }
    }
```

1. How do  I call bird in the main, I also tried to call the method from a object of the class but that didn't work
2. Does it even make sense to do this (I try to avoid static methods as much as possible).

Comment: `bird` and `birdSpeech` are *instance* methods on the `Program` class.  Do you know how to call instance methods?

Comment: I forgot to delete the program parameter from when there was still a object from the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An object reference is required to access non-static member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992681/an-object-reference-is-required-to-access-non-static-member)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method can be made static without changing the code, you should make it static. To answer your question though, you can create an instance of Program in your Main function and call the non-static methods through it.

```cs
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Program();
            p.bird();
        }

        public void bird()
        {
            birdSpeech();
        }

        public void birdSpeech()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Chirp Chirp");
        }
}
```

Comment: Although this works it is better to create a new class that contains the methods bird() and BirdSpeech(), instantiate that class and call the methods. The Program class is not really ment to be instantiated. Because you can doesn't mean you should :-)

Comment: `The Program is not really to be instantiated.` While it's not the best way to structure a program, there is nothing special about the class that contains the `static void Main` method that makes it "not meant to be instantiated".

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        var p = new Program();
        p.bird(p);
    }

    public void bird(Program program)
    {
        birdSpeech();
    }

    public void birdSpeech()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chirp Chirp");
    }
}
```